# How to reference self type in default template arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, standards, std

We have an `reference_counted` template and an default `default_deallocator` class as following:

```
template <class T>
class default_deallocator {
     void operator()(T* obj) {
         delete obj;
     }
};

template <class T>
class reference_counted: T
{
public:
   void retain() {ref_count++;}
   void release() {
        ref_count --;
        if (ref_count == 0) {
            delete this;
        }
   }
}
```

We want to add the deallocator for the `reference_counted` class. But we don't know how to write the default template argument, because the compiler will complain about recursive type reference.

```
//VS2015 says: fatal error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex
template <class T, class D = default_deallocator<reference_counted<T>>>  <---
class reference_counted: T
{
public:
   void retain() {ref_count++;}
   void release() {
        ref_count --;
        if (ref_count == 0) {
            D deallocator;
            deallocator.operator()(this);
        }
   }
}
```

I understand this error.
So the question is how to reference current class type in template default argument or other way to implement this design pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an higher-kinded type *(a "template template parameter")*:

```
template <class T, template <typename...> class D = default_deallocator>  
class reference_counted: T
{
public:
   void retain() {}
   void release() {

        D<reference_counted<T, D>> deallocator;
        deallocator(this);

   }
};
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4pi82mZpkNJI9k1C)

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class T, class D_in = void>
class reference_counted: T
{
public:
  using D = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_same_v<D_in, void>,
    default_deallocator<reference_counted>,
    D_in
  >;
  void retain() {ref_count++;}
  void release() {
    ref_count --;
    if (ref_count == 0) {
        D deallocator;
        deallocator.operator()(this);
    }
  }
};
```